# How can I match the value in other sheet and update the status

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a warehouse inventory file to help the clerk to key in the in/out record.

Details:

- Sheet1=data input
- Sheet2=every in/out record
- Sheet3=the status of every items
- Sheet4=available items

I had created a button to save the data to **sheet2** and **sheet3** from **sheet1**.

Question: If the sheet1 C9 is the item name, and sheet1 C11 is the update status

Then sheet3 D:D = items name, sheet3 E:E = items status

How can I match the items name and update the status?

Comment: On Sheet1 do you keep the name and status on same column?

Comment: no...i will clear the data in sheet1

Comment: Okay then update your question once you do that